# How do I iterate through an array that is nested inside an object that is in turn nested in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

What I want to accomplish:

1. To retrieve all licenseTypes (digger and shovler) so that I can insert them in a header div.
2. To retrieve the respective licenseTypes' subLicenses to be used in a subheading (or maybe body) depending on the view.

My array looks like this:

```
const licenseType = [
    {
      diggerLisense: [
        "Shallow Digger",
        "Deep Digger"
      ]
    },
      shoverlerLicense: [
        "Poop shovler",
        "Grass shovler"
      ]
    }
 ]
```

So basically, I have this structure:

licenseType > subLicenseType > subSubLicenseType

I specifically decided on this nested order for three reasons:

- To map over the licenseTypes (digger and shovler) so that it can be used in a card Heading
- To map over the respective subLicenseTypes (Shallow Digger, Deep Digger, Poop shover, Grass shovler) to be used in the same cards subheading.  For some reason I think it's easier to handle state this way.
- To keep all license types in a neat object structure that can be exported/imported throughout my project.

Any help or accusations is greatly appreciated here.  BTW, I have searched other questions and nothing exactly like the structure I have described here.

Edit:  I want to thank the overwhelming and swift response that you've all offered. I'm amazed at how quickly you people help.  This is my first question on here and I can't believe the speed of the response.

I am currently working the suggestions that were offered including the one that suggests a different format.  I will post a fiddle of the end result later when I'm done. Thanks all you members of the stackoverflow community

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate the `licenseType` with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). For each object get the first [entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and return whatever you want to display:

```js
const licenseType = [{"diggerLisense":["Shallow Digger","Deep Digger"]},{"shoverlerLicense":["Poop shovler","Grass shovler"]}];
 
const result = licenseType.map((o) => {
  const [license, subLicenses] = Object.entries(o)[0];
  
  return `
    <h1>${license}</h1>
    <ul>
      ${subLicenses.map((s) => `<li>${s}</li>`).join('\n')}
    </ul>
  `;
});

demo.innerHTML = result.join('\n');
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

However, having a changing key in an object, complicates it needlessly. I suggest a slightly different format:

```
{
    license: 'digger',
    sub: ['Shallow Digger', 'Deep Digger']
}
```

```js
const licenseType = [{ "license": "digger", "sub": ["Shallow Digger","Deep Digger"]},{ "license": "shoverler", sub: ["Poop shovler","Grass shovler"]}];
 
const result = licenseType.map(({ license, sub }) => `
  <h1>${license}</h1>
  <ul>
    ${sub.map((s) => `<li>${s}</li>`).join('\n')}
  </ul>
`);

demo.innerHTML = result.join('\n');
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: You may want to `join("")` that `subLicenses.map` array to get rid of those commas (which took me some while to track them down haha).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
licenseType.forEach(element => {
    element[Object.keys(element)[0]].forEach(subTypes => {
         console.log(subTypes);
     })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your current data set, you can do something like this.

However, it would be easier if your top level data structure was an object, not an array.

```js
const licenseType = [
    {
      diggerLisense: [
        "Shallow Digger",
        "Deep Digger"
      ]
    },
    {
      shoverlerLicense: [
        "Poop shovler",
        "Grass shovler"
      ]
    }
 ];

 const getLicenses = () => licenseType.map(license => Object.keys(license)[0]);

 const getData = (toFind) => licenseType.find(license => Object.keys(license)[0] === toFind);

 const getSubtypes = (license) => {
   const data = getData(license);
   if (data) {
     subTypes = data[license];
   }
   return subTypes;
 };
 
 console.log(getLicenses());
 console.log(getSubtypes('shoverlerLicense'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LicenseType is an array So you can access the license type like licenseType[i] where it represents the element of the array. for sub license type use 

sublicensetype = [] 
for (i = 0; i < licenseType.length; i++) { 
    for ( var k in licenseType[i]) sublicenseType.push(k) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8s55qjq/2/):

```
licenseType.forEach(function (type) {
  console.log('type', type);
  Object.keys(type).forEach(function (typeKey) {
   console.log('typeKey',typeKey);
   console.log('typeValues',type[typeKey]);
  });    
});
```

Also, you have a syntax error in your initial array:

```
const licenseType = [
  {
    diggerLisense: [
      "Shallow Digger",
      "Deep Digger"
    ]
  },
  { //this bracket was missing
    shoverlerLicense: [
      "Poop shovler",
      "Grass shovler"
    ]
  }
 ]
```